# FBSDK Login - SFSafariViewController is disabled?

Tags: ios, authentication, facebook-login, fbsdk, sfsafariviewcontroller

I've had an issue on my app overnight that I thought was a coding bug. The issue is that the SFSafariViewController login window (Safari based) - is no longer being presented. Instead, it is launching a new Safari app, and once I log in, I now get the native iOS dialog "Open his page in  "XXXXXApp"? I didn't change any settings, didn't play with anything at all. After downloading the source for the FSBDK iOS and debugging, it turns out that "SFSafariViewController" is being disabled by facebook explicitly.

I made a graph call, the same one that the app uses to start up to this endpoint:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/<app-id>?fields=app_events_feature_bitmask%2Cname%2Cdefault_share_mode%2Cios_dialog_configs%2Cios_sdk_dialog_flows.os_version%289.3.0%29%2Cios_sdk_error_categories%2Csupports_implicit_sdk_logging%2Cgdpv4_nux_enabled%2Cgdpv4_nux_content%2Cios_supports_native_proxy_auth_flow%2Cios_supports_system_auth%2Capp_events_session_timeout&format=json&include_headers=false&sdk=ios`

And the response appears to disable the controller SFSafariViewController. The evidence in this portion of the payload:

`"ios_sdk_dialog_flows": {
      "default": {
         "use_native_flow": true,
         "use_safari_vc": false
      }
   }`

Previously, the use_safari_vc value was set to true. In anyone answers, please keep in mind I want to use the Safari View Controller - but not launching safari as it falls back to now. The latest behaviour asks to open my app, which I thought the Safari View Controller was meant to solve! Also keep in mind that everything was functioning well until this morning. I've tried recreating my app multiple times, but the same behaviour still persists.

Help, my user experience with Facebook is now terrible (and note, I don't care about using native behaviour - I just want Safari View Controller again!)

I'm using v4.15.0 of the Facebook SDK

Cheers

Comment: Same here - all our apps use Safari for Login, instead of SFSafariViewController. Strange behavior!!

Comment: I logged a bug with the facebook developer system, and now I get the expected behaviour from the server:



`ios_sdk_dialog_flows: {
default: {
use_native_flow: false,
use_safari_vc: true
},
message: {
use_native_flow: true
}
}`

However, there has no been official response yet as my bug is still "Open". Oh well, at least it is working again!

Answer (score 0):

I got word from Facebook developers group that it was an issue on the server side, and that change has been reverted.